# Is there an easy way to abort with status code 429?

Tags: python, flask

Trying to abort from a "before_request" handler (in Flask) with that code gives the following error: `LookupError: no exception for 429`. Is there a way to fix this?

Here's the code that triggers the error:

```
key = "ip:{}:account-requests".format(request.remote_addr)

# Determine how many requests have been made in the past day
# by this API.
requests_made = r.get(key) or 0

if requests_made >= max_requests:
    abort(429) #HTTP Too Many Requests
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can do like this in Flask

```
if requests_made >= max_requests:
    return '429 error', 429
```