# Flask - How to create custom abort() code?

Tags: python, flask, abort

Flask has a good error handler by using `abort()` or when the error truly occurred.

From Flask documentation there is an example for error 404 handler:

```
@app.errorhandler(404)
def not_found(error):
    return render_template('404.html'), 404
```

So, I tried to create custom error code like

```
if False:
    abort(777)

@app.errorhandler(777)
def something_is_wrong(error):
    return render_template('777.html'), 777
```

But it does not work and the Werkzeug debugger says: LookupError: no exception for 777

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11278671/is-there-an-easy-way-to-abort-with-status-code-429) which says I should do it like this:

```
if False:
    return '777 error', 777
```

Unfortunately, the code above produce white-screen, even the Werkzeug debugger does not come out

I know I can simply do:

```
if False:
    return render_template('777.html')
```

But it will make the code cleaner if I use the `abort()`. Is there any way to create custom error code?

Comment: If you're using Flask 1.0, it seems that the approach has changed and you can raise and catch custom exceptions: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/patterns/apierrors/

Answer (score 51, accepted):

The list of possible HTTP status codes is fixed by the Internet Assigned Numbers Authority, so you cannot add a custom one. Werkzeug recognizes this and tries to stop you sending a meaningless code to the browser. Look through the [list of status codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes) to find one that matches your error and use that one.

Edit: **Adding status codes to Werkzeug/Flask**

```
import werkzeug.exceptions as ex
from flask import Flask, abort

class PaymentRequired(ex.HTTPException):
    code = 402
    description = '<p>You will pay for this!</p>'

abort.mappings[402] = PaymentRequired

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def mainpage():
    abort(402)

@app.errorhandler(402)
def payme(e):
    return 'Pay me!'

app.run()
```

Comment: Thanks, I use error 400 bad_request for when the user manually typed wrong value in the URL (because the URL contains user input from dropdown list). **It works, but is it the correct one?**

Comment: Probably, depends on why you're refusing the input. Another appropriate / common code could be 404, or maybe even 403 if you're blocking for security reason.

Comment: What about 402? That one is undefined in werkzeug but it should be a valid one.

Comment: @ultimatebuster It's undefined because, as the list states, it is reserved for future use. I doubt that "Payment Required" is an accurate description of your error, so would advise against 402. Just do `return something_is_wrong()` instead of `abort(777)`. It's clean and not against the standard.

Comment: Actually that's exactly what I want to say. I want to say: payment is required for this service.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I'll look into the Werkzeug source to see how a new error code could be added.

Comment: I need to send back `504` (gateway timeout) but Flask doesn't seem to support that either. Any idea why?

Comment: `abort.mappings` no longer seems to exist; use this instead: `exceptions.default_exceptions[402] = PaymentRequired`

Comment: In my case (Flask==0.11.1, Werkzeug==0.11.10) it abort.mapping[402] = PaymentRequired, not "mappings"

Comment: in Flask 0.11.1, `abort.mapping` instead of `abort.mappings`,and you don't need change `abort.mapping`, `abort.mapping` is `default_exceptions`, you can `from werkzeug.exceptions import default_exceptions`.

Comment: Well technically you *can* use a custom code, but your client might not understand it. The Twitter API does that with "420" for example, which is not an official code.

Answer (score 18):

Depending on the reading of the question this might come in handy.

There is an easier way to add customer error page handling for a specific exception, you can do this:

```
class MyCustom404(Exception):
    pass

@app.errorhandler(404)
def page_not_found(error):
    return render_template("errors/404.html"), 404

@app.errorhandler(MyCustom404)
def special_page_not_found(error):
    return render_template("errors/custom_404.html"), 404
```

...then trigger your new handler when you need it with

```
raise MyCustom404
```

See the [docs here](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.Flask.errorhandler).

Answer (score 10):

In my case, Flask==0.11.1 Werkzeug==0.11.10

I use abort the http status code 451 for example.

if you want use abort() with a code,a int number,like abort(451), at first you should create a custom HTTPException, a subclass of HTTPException.and append your HTTPException to `default_exceptions`.

```
from werkzeug.exceptions import HTTPException, default_exceptions,  Aborter
class UnavailableForLegalReasons(HTTPException):
    code = 451
    description = 'BIG BROTHER IS WATCHING YOU'

default_exceptions[451] = UnavailableForLegalReasons
abort = Aborter()  # don't from flask import abort

@app.errorhandler(451)
def uflr(e):
    return e, 451

@app.route('/debug')
def debug():
    abort(451)
```

then when you access the path in browser, you can look this
[image]

but the http reason phrase is UNKNOWN,

you can change it

```
from werkzeug.http import HTTP_STATUS_CODES
HTTP_STATUS_CODES[451] = 'Unavailable For Legal Reasons'  # or even empty
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could also use [Flask API](http://www.flaskapi.org/) and its error handling system:

http://www.flaskapi.org/api-guide/exceptions/